# Getting a 503 error with NodeJS and ExressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I get a 503 error using NodeJS. My function works in `localhost` but on my remote server I get a 503 error.

**Functions :**

```
function postEdit(request, response) {
  var updatedParams = request.body.updatedParams,
      blockName     = request.params.blockname,
      primaryColor, secondaryColor, variables, scssStr;

  if (blockName === 'themeparam') {
    primaryColor = updatedParams.primary_color;
    secondaryColor = updatedParams.secondary_color;
    variables = updatedParams.variables;

    if (primaryColor || secondaryColor || variables) {

      scssStr = fs.readFileSync('./public/sass/_functions.scss', 'utf8');
      scssStr += fs.readFileSync('./public/sass/_settings.scss', 'utf8');

      if (primaryColor) {
        scssStr = scssStr.replace(/\$main-color:.+;/g, '$main-color: ' + primaryColor + ';');
      }

      if (secondaryColor) {
        scssStr = scssStr.replace(/\$secondary-color:.+;/g, '$secondary-color: ' + secondaryColor + ';');
      }

      scssStr += fs.readFileSync('./public/sass/app.scss', 'utf8');
      scssStr = scssStr.replace(/@import.+;/g, '');

      if (variables) {
        scssStr += variables;
      }

      fs.readdir('./public/sass/components', function(err, files) {

        files.forEach(function(file) {
          scssStr += fs.readFileSync('./public/sass/components/' + file, 'utf8');
        });

        fs.readdir('./public/sass/shortcodes', function(err, shortcodeFiles) {

          shortcodeFiles.forEach(function(shortcodeFile) {
            scssStr += fs.readFileSync('./public/sass/shortcodes/' + shortcodeFile, 'utf8');
          });

          fs.writeFileSync('./public/uploads/theme.scss', scssStr);

          sass.render({
            file: './public/uploads/theme.scss'
          }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            fs.writeFileSync('./public/uploads/theme.css', result.css);
          });
        });
      });
    } else {
      fs.stat('./public/uploads/theme.scss', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        if (!err) {
          fs.unlinkSync('./public/uploads/theme.scss');
          fs.unlinkSync('./public/uploads/theme.css');
        }
      });
    }
  }

  if (blockName === 'robotparam') {
    fs.writeFileSync('./public/robots.txt', updatedParams.robot);
  }

  editJsonFile(request, response, './configs/options.json', function(options) {
    _.forEach(updatedParams, function(value, name) {
      var blockParam = _.find(options.blocks, { name: blockName }),
          param = _.find(blockParam.params, { name: name });
      param.value = value;
    });
  }, OptionController.baseUrl + '/edit/block/' + blockName);
}

function editJsonFile(request, response, jsonFile, updater, redirectUrl) {
  fs.readFile(jsonFile, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    var options = JSON.parse(data);
    updater(options);
    fs.writeFile(jsonFile, JSON.stringify(options, null, 4), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      request.flash('success', 'Done !');
      response.redirect(redirectUrl);
    });
  });
}
```

**Error 503 :**

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ****** Port 443
```

Is there any solution to get the error message to find the issue ?

Comment: Can you provide your apache and node service configuration? My hunch is that apache can't make contact with your node service. It would be good to confirm the ports etc.

Comment: Looks like your apache is mis configured and isn't pointing at your express app correctly. How's your apache config set up?

Comment: I'm using PM2 to launch my node application. And it works except this function. Other pages on my application are working well.